# How to extract item if its key (array) contains each and every value from another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexeddb

I'm new to IndexedDB. I want to put this kind of data into indexed database:

```
 var items = [{
     title: 'A',
     tags: ['h', 'f', 'g', 's', 't']
 }, {
     title: 'B',
     tags: ['g', 'i', 'm']
 }, {
     title: 'C',
     tags: ['f', 'l', 't', 'd']
 }, {
     title: 'D',
     tags: ['i', 'u', 'v']
 }, {
     title: 'E',
     tags: ['i', 'g']
 }];
```

Besides, another array will serve as a source of my favorite tags:

```
 var tagsArray = ['g', 'i']
```

(Of course, this array may contain any number of tags, not only two).
I want to extract all items containing each and every tag from that `tagsArray` and get this array:

```
 var result = [{
     title: 'B',
     tags: ['g', 'i', 'm']
 }, {
     title: 'E',
     tags: ['i', 'g']
 }]
```

But even after `objectStore.createIndex('tags', 'tags', {multiEntry: true, unique: false})`, I don't know how to go further. I don't even understand what exactly are `multiEntry` and `unique` parameters intended for. Does indexedDB allow to extract item only if its key (Array) contains each and every one of the provided keywords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB. While you are there, you can take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=IndexedDB%2FIDBObjectStore#createIndex().